# Generic constructor takes a class object of Type T, and returns T, this time T is a List

Tags: java, generics, collections, parameterized-types

`protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse`

is a method that returns a type of `<T>` ,  but I need `<T>` to be a `List<T>` or other kind of generic collection. This is because I am serializing objects from the network, and sometimes those objects become lists.

My objects are implementing required methods, so I can't just change the return type to `List<T>`; what can I do?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do. Can you post some code you've tried?

Comment: @Leo, actually I have an idea I'll resort to make a class that holds a List<T> and pass that in instead

Comment: looks like something that will work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample, `getErrors()` and `getWarnings()` return `List<T>`

```
public interface ErrorHolder<T> {

    public void addError(T t);

    public int totalErrors();

    public boolean hasErrors();

    public void addWarning(T t);

    public int totalWarnings();

    public boolean hasWarnings();

    public List<T> getErrors();

    public List<T> getWarnings();
}
```

and in the implementing class -

```
private List<T> errors = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void addError(T t) {
        errors.add(t);

    }

public List<T> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
```